# Edition of many objects in one model table in one form. Django

Tags: django, forms

I have a very simple form to edit one field in the table, it looks like this.

```
class TimeEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Time
        fields = ('free_or_no',)
```

Now I would like to create a view in which I have many objects from one table and all of my query set can be edited in one place. How can I transfer many objects to the unit edition? 
I was looking for answers on the forum but they mainly refer to the editing of many models by one form and not many objects in one table.

Any help will be appreciated.

**My models.py**

```
class Time(models.Model):
    day_time = models.ForeignKey(DayTime, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    compartment = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    free_or_no = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def time_edit(request):
    time = get_object_or_404(Time, pk=pk) # how to replace it correctly in the query set collections, what can I use? like this Time.objects.all()[:12]
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TimeEditForm(request.POST, instance=time)
        if form.is_valid():
            time = form.save(commit=False)
            time.save()
            return redirect('account')
    else:
        form = TimeEditForm(instance=time)
    return render(request, 'time_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: You are looking for modelformsets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

Comment: This is great !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the whole code editing many objects in one form.

```
test = Time.objects.filter(day_time__day_name='Monday')
TimeFormSet = modelformset_factory(Time, fields=('free_or_no',))
if request.method == "POST":
    formset = TimeFormSet(
        request.POST,
        queryset=Time.objects.filter(day_time__day_name='Monday'),
    )
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:account'))
else:
    formset = TimeFormSet(queryset=Time.objects.filter(day_time__day_name='Monday'))
```